# Check For Variable Length

Tags: php, magento

My following script will take all skus from database and will loop through it and call API php code, I would like to skip if the $productSku ($sku) length is 10 (It's alphanumeric). So anything more than 10 is the SKU I need the script to work with if it's 10 digits skip to next one.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('gt' => $productId))
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
foreach ($collection as $product){
     $productSku[]=$product->getSku();
}
if(count($productSku)){
foreach($productSku as $sku){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(strlen($sku) <= 10) continue;
```

should do the trick..or you could do it before assigning to $productSku..

```
if(strlen($product->getSku()) <= 10) continue;
```